# How to level a floor that got out of level from a beam breaking underneath the house

Tags: subfloor, self-leveling-concrete

So I tried to get pictures, but I couldn't get any that you could really see how unlevel the floors are. I want to be clear, I am a frame carpenter who is familiar with the correct terms, and I am talking about a beam, not an I-joist. I was able to repair the beam and level the joist around it. The floor is much better, but it sat on top of that broken beam for over 12 years so its not great. Its good enough to where you can't see it in a photo, but bad enough to where its still noticeable. Using an 8 foot level I can tell its off as much as 3/8 an inch in some places. What I am wondering is if I can use a self-leveler on that, or if I should rip the floors up and put new sub flooring?

Comment: Why not fox the beam it may take time to fully Jack it into place, using leveling compound would be a hack compared to fixing the root problem.

Comment: i fixed the beam. Its solid and level. The prublem is some of the joist and sub floor in about a 8X12 foot area got warped in some places from sitting like like. im guessing some of the I joist are a little of to for it to span in between them. The beem broke years ago, and she left it like that. I may try ti lift up on the I beams, but I have no way of locking them in if raising them helps. At this point I either have to use self leveler, or replace the sub floor & joists.

Comment: Are the doors and windows working properly? Adding a large amount of leveling compound may end up causing other problems.